# How to fill the gap created by removed div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a HTML5 page.
I want to make the following div auto fill the gap when removing the upper div dynamically using a button. Currently, when I remove the upper div, a big gap would be generated. The following div would not move up to auto fill the gap.

Before removing some selection div:
[image]

After removing for some selection div:
[image]

Here is the code I use:

```html
<style>
    .field{ display: inline; }
</style>   

<button class="button3" type="button" id="add_more">Add Discipline</button><p>  

<script>
$('#add_more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ++current_id;
    $("p").before("           <div class='field' id="+ current_id + ">         <select style=\"min-height:30px;min-width:100px;\" name=" + current_id +  ">\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" selected disabled hidden>--Select--</option>\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" name=\"discipline_name_all2\">All Disciplines</option>\n" +
        "                        {% for discipline in query_results %}\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"{{ discipline.name }}\" name=\"discipline_name2\">{{ discipline.name }}</option>\n" +
        "                        {% endfor %}\n" +
        "                    </select>&ensp;&nbsp;\n" +
        "                    <button class=\"button4\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"delete_button_clicked2(this.id)\" id="+ current_id + ">&#x2716;</button></div><br><br>");

    console.log(current_id);
});
    
function delete_button_clicked2(id) {      
    var sel = document.getElementById(id);    
    sel.remove();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, as per my understanding, you want to fill the remaining space of a wrapper element if the child div is `display: none`, right ?

Comment: yes, if the middle div is removed, other div should auto fill the gap

Comment: Use `flexbox`, the child elements will auto occupy the space in case one/multiple removed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you have is that you remove the div, but not the breaks.

```
    $("p").before("           <div class='field' id="+ current_id + ">         <select style=\"min-height:30px;min-width:100px;\" name=" + current_id +  ">\n" +
    "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" selected disabled hidden>--Select--</option>\n" +
    "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" name=\"discipline_name_all2\">All Disciplines</option>\n" +
    "                        {% for discipline in query_results %}\n" +
    "                        <option value=\"{{ discipline.name }}\" name=\"discipline_name2\">{{ discipline.name }}</option>\n" +
    "                        {% endfor %}\n" +
    "                    </select>&ensp;&nbsp;\n" +
    "                    <button class=\"button4\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"delete_button_clicked2(this.id)\" id="+ current_id + ">&#x2716;</button>
<!-- These two br will stay... -->
</div><br><br>");
```

If you place them *inside* the div, removing will work without leaving a space behind.

Here's a working example:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .field{ display: inline; }
</style>   

<button class="button3" type="button" id="add_more">Add Discipline</button><br><p>  

<script>
var current_id = 0;
$('#add_more').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    ++current_id;
    $("p").before("<div class='field' id="+ current_id + "><select style=\"min-height:30px;min-width:100px;\" name=" + current_id +  ">\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" selected disabled hidden>--Select--</option>\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"All Disciplines\" name=\"discipline_name_all2\">All Disciplines</option>\n" +
        "                        {% for discipline in query_results %}\n" +
        "                        <option value=\"{{ discipline.name }}\" name=\"discipline_name2\">{{ discipline.name }}</option>\n" +
        "                        {% endfor %}\n" +
        "                    </select>&ensp;&nbsp;\n" +
        "                    <button class=\"button4\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"delete_button_clicked2(this.id)\" id="+ current_id + 
        // <br><br> inside the div
        ">&#x2716;</button><br><br></div>"); 

    console.log(current_id);
});
    
function delete_button_clicked2(id) {      
    var sel = document.getElementById(id);    
    sel.remove();
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

use for block with selects:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
```